# How to solve vs code - gopls command is not available

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

The "gopls" command is not available. Run "go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls" to install.

I'm running on go 1.14. Not sure what will happen, if I follow the instruction.

[image]

---

```
Installing 1 tool at the configured GOBIN: /usr/local/go/bin in module mode.
  gopls

Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: downloading golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.6.9\ngo: golang.org/x/tools/gopls upgrade => v0.6.9\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.1.1-0.20210319172145-bda8f5cee399
...

1 tools failed to install.

gopls: failed to install gopls(golang.org/x/tools/gopls): Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.6.9
go: golang.org/x/tools/gopls upgrade => v0.6.9
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.1.1-0.20210319172145-bda8f5cee399
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210124154548-22da62e12c0c
go: downloading honnef.co/go/tools v0.1.1
go: downloading golang.org/x/mod v0.4.1
golang.org/x/mod/semver
...

go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls: copying /var/folders/gq/bwl3jmx562x5twchgxvb6mlh0000gn/T/go-build703164122/b001/exe/a.out: open /usr/local/go/bin/gopls: permission denied
 no output
```

Comment: How about running `go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls` to install gopls? No, seriously.

Comment: actually, I am not sure, what the gopls is used for ...

Comment: Then read about it: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/gopls

Comment: I was getting similar error about `goplay` command. So I ran `go get -v github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay` from command prompt as it was mentioned in the error message and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The extension depends on other tools to provide necessary features. `gopls` is one of the core tools necessary to provide language features like code completion, navigation, search, etc for go language. See the list of tools the extension depends on: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/tools.md

"Install" will install the 'gopls'.
"Install All" will install all the missing tools.

If you are using go1.14, either click the button (or run "Go: Install/Update Tools" command from the command palette) or, install tools in module mode with the following command (not just `go get` because with go1.14, the go command will try to install the tool in GOPATH mode which isn't what you want.)

```
cd /tmp/
GO111MODULE=on go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls
```

Comment: when I just click the "Install" option button, provided in vs code, I got below info :

Comment: Yes, need privilege and network, both ok.  Solved this issue in terminal. Not in IDE.

Comment: I have followed the step of 
`cd /tmp  GO111MODULE=on go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls`
and no error met, why vs code still throw the warn window out?

Comment: gopls must be installed into the GOPATH that VSC uses, e.g., run the install when logged in as the same user that runs VSC

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem and solved it with:

```
go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
```

if you get the error:

```
x\tools@v0.1.13-0.20220811140653-b901dff69f70\internal\lsp\source\hover.go:23:2: module golang.org/x/text@latest found (v0.3.7), but does not contain package golang.org/x/text/unicode/runenames
```

try using:

```
go clean -modcache
go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
```

Comment: Cleaning the modcache did it for me. I am using devbox.

Answer (score 1):

Here I solved using the command `brew install gopls`

Comment: Error: gopls: Failed to download resource "gopls_bottle_manifest"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/gopls/manifests/0.11.0

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora you can resolve the issue by installing the golang-x-tools-gopls package.

```
# dnf install golang-x-tools-gopls
```

Answer (score 0):

1. run go env
2. if you see GOSUMDB="on" or GOSUMDB="of",
3. modify this item go env -w GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
4. Execute go mod tidy again
5. Install gopls and other tools

Answer (score 0):

Either run `go mod init main.go` or manually create a `go.mod` file in the relevant folder